# How do I apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev -y in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I am trying to install something on Windows and one of the requirements is:

```
apt-get install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev -y
```

Is there a Windows equivalent for these libraries?

FWIW, this is a pre-requisite for a python program from sourceforge.

Comment: What are you trying to install. The documentation on what you are trying to install might have some information on how to make it run on Windows. Python packages that use compiled code are notably hard to port to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is a command for installing packages (libraries) on Linux. So, it cannot be executed on Windows operating systems.

If you really have to work on Windows here are the alternatives:

1. Use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and try Cygwin's installer ([apt-cyg](http://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/)).
2. Use a virtualization software like [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and run Linux virtually on Windows.

Comment: There no windows equivalent of these libraries?

Comment: There must be equivalents on Windows of course. But they are not supposed to work with your python program.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, as the `apt` package manager is only provided for Debian and Debian-based Linux distributions. However, you can install Debian or Ubuntu using [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) and then run that command in the provided BASH shell. Otherwise, both can be downloaded here: [libjpeg](https://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/), [libpng](https://libpng.sourceforge.io/).